# How to upload separate HTML file to wordpress site via FTP client?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, ftp

Hello I have a wordpress website set up, but have a separate HTML file project that I would like to upload to my website so that I can link to the page within my portfolio. Simply, I just need the HTML page up and running on my site so that I can link to it, without affecting my existing wordpress site. Should I just upload it to the public_html? I also have a js folder that is required for the page to function, can I upload that to my site directory without worrying about the existing wordpress site being affected? Thank you!

Comment: Yes; creating unrelated new files will not suddenly break WordPress.

Comment: Thanks, where should I upload said file?

Comment: if  you create a new directory and name file `index.html` will be able to access it with just the directory name in url. Can stick your js in that directory or anywhere else you prefer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you can. You will have to upload your html files under 
   "wp-content->themes" folder and no bad effect will occur in existing wordpress site.

Comment: I have also been told to add it to the public_html folder, should I just upload it to the themes folder even though it isn't a wordpress theme?

Comment: yes, you can. there is no any chances to affect wordpress site